# Error in a class in xamarin form in a get request

Tags: api, xamarin, xamarin.android, get, request

I am doing a little exercise in xamarin forms to get a request from an api, and the api return me this

```
{
"valido": true,
"nombre": "Anderson",
"apellido": "Laverde Gracia",
"email": "ander.laverde.dev@gmail.com",
"periodo": "0985",
"emplid": "8923082",
"x-t6519fdd1s5q": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NTk3MTQ1MTUsInN1YiI6ImFuZGVyc29ubGF2ZXJkZTE2In0.T8his-2cpGgFwkxmDGOeZ2rAGKIrSyrgPvfUs2xZUkiD6Z4hi7Dhg-p28y8dKBr3TW_97kqnSEY1Pg-k5AYuAA",
"token_expire_in": 1559714515418,
"roles": [
"3"
]
}
```

But When I create a class in xamarin with this parameters all works

```
 public class MyUser
    {
        public bool valido { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string periodo { get; set; }
        public string emplid { get; set; }
        public string x-t6519fdd1s5q { get; set; }
        public List<string> roles { get; set; }

}
}
```

except this

```
 public string x-t6519fdd1s5q { get; set; }
```

The error says that x-t6519fdd1s5q  isnt recognized as string, and i need this value. how can i access to it ?

Help me please..

Comment: Dash (`-`) is not a valid character in a variable name in C#. You could use another valid name such as `x_t6519fdd1s5q`.

Comment: thanks, but when i get the request, it return me this parameter, if a change to x_t6519fdd1s5q how can a read public string x-t6519fdd1s5q { get; set; } ?

Comment: We can map returned JSON parameters to our destination language naming conventions. All JSON libraries provide us with such mapping. Therefore you better define that specific parameter as `X_t6519fdd1s5q` in your C# code and include a mapping annotation, something like `[JsonProperty("x-t6519fdd1s5q")]` above that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `JsonProperty` attribute to map that value to a valid C# name

```
[JsonProperty("x-t6519fdd1s5q")]
public string x_t6519fdd1s5q { get; set; }
```